# Не выходит сделать сценарий, который будет проверять заполнены ли обязательные поля формы

Tags: php

Суть задания такова: необходимо разработать сценарий, который будет проверять заполнены ли обязательные поля формы. Если поля не заполнены тогда выводим подсказку, что нужно заполнить. В другом случае выводим информацию о пользователе. Все по идеи должно быть в одном файле с расширением php.
В коде три функции:
print_form выводит форму на экран
check_form проверяет заполнены ли обязательные поля
confirm_form отображает выходные данные

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Контактна інформація </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 $f_name=$_POST['f_name'];
 $l_name=$_POST['l_name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $zip=$_POST['zip'];
 $object=$_POST['object'];


function print_form($f_name,$l_name,$email,$zip,$object)
{ ?>
 <form action="form_start.php" method="post">
 <table cellspasing="2" cellpedding="2" border="1">
 <td>Ім'я</td><td><input name="f_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $f_name ?>"></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
   <td>Прізвище<b>*</b></td><td><input name="l_name" type="text" value="<?php print $_name?>"</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Email адреса<b>*</b></td><td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php print $email?>">
    </td>
    </tr>
     
     <tr>
       <td>Поштовий індекс<b>*</b></td>
     <td><input name="zip" type="text" value="<?php print $zip?>">
        </td>
         </tr>
         
         <tr>
           <td>Улюблений предмет</td>
            <td><input name="object" type="text" value="<?php print $object?>">
            </td>
            </tr>
            
           </table>
           
           <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Надіслати">
           <input type="reset" value="Відмінити">
           </form>
           <? 
    
    
} 





function check_form($f_name,$l_name,$email,$zip,$object)
{


 if(!$l_name||!$email||!$zip):echo "<h3>Помилка у заповнені форми</h3>";
 if($l_name)
 {
  echo"<h3>Ви не заповнили поле<b>Прізвище</b></h3>";
 }
 if(isset($email))
    {
     echo "<h3>Ви не заповнили поле <b>Email адреса</b></h3>";
    }
 
 if(!$zip)
 {
  echo "<h3>Ви не заповнили поле <b>Поштовий індекс</b></h3>";
 }
 
 print_form($f_name,$l_name,$email,$zip,$object);
 else:
  confirm_form($f_name,$l_name,$email,$zip,$object);
  endif;
}

function confirm_form($f_name,$l_name,$email,$zip,$object)
{
 


 
 
 ?>
 
 
 
 
 <h2>Дякуємо! Слідуюча інформація була успішно надіслана</h2>
 <b>Контактна інформація</b>
 <?
 
 $f_name=$_POST['f_name'];
 $l_name=$_POST['l_name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $zip=$_POST['zip'];
 $object=$_POST['object'];

 
 echo "<br>$f_name $l_name<br>$email<br>Поштовий індекс:$zip<br>Улюблений предмет:$object\n";
}

if(!$submit):
?>
<h3>Будь-ласка, введіть інформацію про себе</h3>
Поля з<b>*</b>обовязкові для заповнення<p>
<?php



print_form("","","","","","");
else:
check_form($f_name,$l_name,$email,$zip,$object);
endif;
 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/docs.php больше нечего добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Либо JavaScript: http://www.formvalidator.net/#reg-form
, либо:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['required_field'])) {
    echo 'Не заполнено обязательное поле';
}
?>
```

Comment: В вопросе нет метки по JS, так что это не ответ.

Comment: @Other, Ок, тогда Ваш вариант кроме JS, и isset().

Comment: JS полезно, но его всегда можно отключить. валидация модели на стороне сервера должна быть обязательно.

Comment: @teran Попробуйте с выключенным JS, зайти на vk.com... Если пользователь отключил JS, значит нужно заставить его включить **`<noscript><p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает скрипты!</p></noscript>`**

Comment: @ВадимПедченко это как-то воспрепятствует отправки невалидного post-запроса?

Comment: @teran, Какого запроса если пользователь не увидит ничего кроме "Ваш браузер не поддерживает скрипты!", на любой странице сайта, если у него не включен JS.

Comment: @ВадимПедченко а вы не умеете запросы отправлять, не используя формы на вэб-страницах, а просто так? Или, например, в Инструментах открыть Сеть-Запрос, изменить данные, и отправить запрос заново?

Answer (score 0):

По моему проще будет добавить в input required:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Надіслати" **required**>
<input type="reset" value="Відмінити" **required**>
```

Comment: И хакеры, умеющие пользоваться консолью браузера, Вам будут очень признательны :)

Comment: по моему следует лучше изучить элементарный php-синтаксис. Даже не "лучше изучить", а хотя бы ознакомится.

Comment: для выделения кода используйте фигурные скобки на панели инструментов редактора